# To find the sum of the given infinite series

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

This is a question from the book 'Differential Calculus' by Joseph Edwards.
Prove that if $x$ be less than unity
$$\frac{1-2x}{1-x+x^2} + \frac{2x-4x^3}{1-x^2+x^4} + \frac{4x^3-8x^7}{1-x^4+x^8} \ldots = \frac{1+2x}{1+x+x^2}$$

As the numerators are negative derivative of the denominators, I tried differentiating the sum of the series
-log{1-x+x^2}-log{1-x^2+x^4}-log{1-x^4+x^8}....but was unable to arrive at the required answer.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please update your question with where you are getting stuck and what you think the approach to the problem should be. We will be happy to guide you further.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the pattern is.  Is the next denominator $1-x^3+x^6$?

Comment: I suspect it's $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{2^j x^{2^j-1} (1 - 2 x^{2^j})}{1 - x^{2^j} + x^{2^{j+1}}} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the equality
$$
\frac{1+x}{1+x^3}\cdot \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^6}\cdot \frac{1+x^4}{1+x^{12} }\cdots=\frac{(1-x)^{-1}}{(1-x^3)^{-1}}\tag 1
$$
To understand the numerator, note that you can prove by induction that
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+x^{2^i})=\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1}x^i
$$
Letting $n\to\infty$, you get
$$
\prod_{i=0}^\infty (1+x^{2^i})=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i=\frac1{1-x}\tag2
$$ For the denominator, substitute $x^3$ into $(2)$.

Next, note that $(1+x)/(1+x^3)=1/(1-x+x^2)$, so $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\frac1{1-x+x^2}\cdot \frac1{1-x^2+x^4}\cdot \frac1{1-x^4+x^8}\cdots =\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}=1+x+x^2\tag{3}
$$
Finally, take the logs of both sides in $(3)$, then differentiate.

Comment: I get it now. By multiplying the terms in the numerators and denominators in (1), we arrive at series which are geometric progressions. We use the information x is less than 1 to find the sum of the infinite GPs.